# Login System on Vanilla Server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am currently working on my vanilla minecraft server. Everything works fine until my friend use my account to /op his account.

I don't want something like this happen. Is there anyway(command) can let player to have register and login system with password like the [AuthMe](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/authme/)
plugin? Note that my server is vanilla so I don't want/cannot install any plugins. This can prevent some player login my server with other player's name. Is there any command that can do this?

Comment: You know you are not supposed to have online=false server, hm? That is the prebuild protection, with that nobody can join server as you unless he has password to your MC account (which nobody should) If you disable online check, then you disable the protection.

Comment: @AntoineHejlík I want everybody can join my server, not only premium players, but also cracked player. Btw, thx for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. The Vanilla platform expects all users to use their own accounts, as that's how it works. Command Blocks can't register commands, nor can they really handle user management properly.

In theory, you can use the `/trigger` command and a unique number as a password. Kick anyone with that username that doesn't have that value set. However, that's unnecessarily complicated and doesn't scale well at all.

The easiest option would just be to *not* give your friend access to your account for any reason whatsoever. If you really want to share accounts while controlling users, you have to use a custom server (you really should anyways -- they're awesome) and plugins.

Comment: Well, thanks! I guess I will have to find another solution

Comment: Not to mention that I don't think command blocks can run /kick.